# Input fields must include specific character to be allowed for the form to submit

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am trying to prevent as much spam form submissions on a lead generation form from happening. The idea is to ensure the email field must include an @ symbol and the website field must include a '.'. How would I go about achieving this with JS.

Just a heads up, I am using contact form 7 on Wordpress so any solutions for that would be amazing.

If you have any questions please ask :)

Comment: CF7 provides field types for email and URLs already, and validation of those is already built-in.

Comment: Use  <input type="email"> within a form it will only allow correct email address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use regex to evaluate your email

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    const reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return reg.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}
```

All you need to do is just pass the entered email to this function and it will help you determine whether its a valid or invalid one